# Why drawline() method cannot draw a line as exact co-ordinate that i passed?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I write this simple code for line drawing  but problem is line start from somewhere. I need to start the line which co-ordinate i passed to the drawline() method. I cannot find why line get margin from left side. I have confusion. i need guideline so that i will solve big problem from this. code and output are attached below.

```
ImageView drawingImageView;
drawingImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewLine);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), (int)getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawingImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    //Line
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    //paint.setAlpha(0x80);


    float startX3=0.0f;
    float startY3=0.0f;
    float stopX3=451.0f;
    float stopY3=553.0f;


    canvas.drawLine(startX3, startY3, stopX3, stopY3, paint);
```

[output (line have margin from left side)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6DBh.png)

Comment: Check the paddings and margins on the `ImageView` and other `View`s in the layout XML.

Comment: @MikeM. ya i already tried out. i cannot get any change.

Comment: @MikeM. i doubt that this issue is related to bitmap that i create. am i right?

Comment: Do you have a `scaleType` set on the `ImageView`?

Comment: And by the way: what you are doing is terrible. Why don't you create a custom `View` and override `onDraw()`?  I am not surprised that you get weird output when doing something like this.

Comment: Or you could also implement a custom `Drawable` or something like that. Android provides many ways to draw stuff, each with their own advantages and disadvantages. You should use them and not try what you are trying to do.

Comment: a hint: add two additional lines of code to see why this happens: `drawingImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)` and `canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE)`

Comment: Thanks @XaverKapeller. it will solved. but in some case where i have to dynamically create custom view component and put it into activity. any idea?